# Trust a self-signed certificate in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, ssl, self-signed

I have a website running on a nodejs server. The website contacts an API which is present on another server. Now, I want to make the connection secure by using SSL. So, I have a self-signed certificate on the API server. My question is that how do I make the nodejs server trust thes self-signed certificate and accept a connection to it.

Comment: https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-self-signed-certificate-example

Comment: In this example will the client trust other CAs also or only the new CA? I mean is the new CA being appended to the list of trusted CAs or replacing the list with only this one?